# How To Create An Algorithm That Combines Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, object

This is what I've tried and it seems like I'm on the right path but I've been trying to tweak this algorithm for a while and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code so far:

```
const getThem = async () => {
        const format2 = 'YYYY/MM/DD';
        const obj = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < data[i].tests.length; j++) {
                for (let z = 0; z < channel.length; z++) {
                    if (data[i].tests[j] === channel[z].id) {
                        const dateTime = moment(channel[z].start).format(format2);
                        const dateTime2 = moment(channel[z].end).format(format2);
                        const dateList = getDateArray(new Date(dateTime), new Date(dateTime2));
                        if (Date.parse(dateTime) > Date.parse('2019-11-15') || Date.parse(dateTime) < Date.parse('2019-11-04')) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!channel[z].end) {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line operator-assignment
                            obj[dateTime] += (1 / data.length);
                        } else {
                            for (let k = 0; k < dateList.length; k++) {
                                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(dateList[k])) {
                                    obj[dateList[k]] = 1 / data.length;
                                } else {
                                    obj[dateList[k]] += (1 / data.length);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        setDates(Array.sort(Object.keys(obj)));
        setValues(Object.values(obj));
    };
```

Comment: How does `expectedChannelUtilizations` is being or shoube be created from those 2 arrays?

Comment: I suppose you want to take unique dates of the range of min start and max end date from `testsResponse` and then check how many % of tests were utilised in that day out of total possible tests in `channelsResponse`. Am I correct?

Comment: e.g., on date `2019-11-04`  there were 2 tests with ids 3 & 4 and total tests are 30 so 2%30 comes out to be 6.6% but the expected output should be 14. How is that?

Comment: Maybe its because tests 3 & 4 are in one channel with id 372 and the total channel response size is 7 so 1%7 is 14%. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Okay I think I got it because for date `2019-11-05` the tests are 1,2,4,9,17,21,26 which are in 6 channels out of 7 and so the % comes out to be 85%. Hmm interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer. The approach is simple. First we loop through all the `testsResponse` data and get the minimum and maximum dates then we iterate through each day from min to max date. For each current day we check the test ids in `testsResponse` data and then we filter the channels data from the tests array in `channelsResponse` data and then finally we take the % by the filtered channels data and total channels response data and push it in the results array. The only catch here is that it will push all the dates between minimum `test.start` and maximum `test.end` dates both inclusive. If you want to exclude the dates for which `testIds` is empty then just before the `results.push()` check if `testIds.length` is not 0. Here is the `getThem()`:

```
// given channelsResponse & testsResponse
const getThem = () => {
 
 // get min and max dates
 let max='';
 let min=new Date().toISOString();
 testsResponse.forEach(test => {
    min=test.start && min.localeCompare(test.start)>0?test.start:min;
    max=test.end && max.localeCompare(test.end)<0?test.end:max;
 });
 
 min=new Date(min.substr(0,10)+'T00:00:00.000Z');
 max=new Date(max.substr(0,10)+'T00:00:00.000Z');
 
 let results = [];
 // loop from min date to max date
 for(var i=min; i<=max; i.setDate(i.getDate()+1)) {
    let p=0;
    let d=i.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    
    // get test ids within the current date
    const testIds = testsResponse.filter(t => d.localeCompare((t.start+'').substr(0,10))>=0 && d.localeCompare((t.end+'').substr(0,10))<=0).map(t => t.id);

    // get channels where above test ids were found
    const channels = channelsResponse.filter(c => c.tests.some(t => testIds.includes(t)));
    
    // calculate %
    p=Math.round(channels.length*100.0/channelsResponse.length);

    // push data for current date to results
    results.push({date: i.toISOString(), utilizationPercentage: p})
 }
 return results;
};

console.log(getThem());
// [{"date":"2019-11-04T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":14},{"date":"2019-11-05T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":86},{"date":"2019-11-06T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":71},{"date":"2019-11-07T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":43},{"date":"2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":57},{"date":"2019-11-09T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":29},{"date":"2019-11-10T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":29},{"date":"2019-11-11T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":57},{"date":"2019-11-12T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":57},{"date":"2019-11-13T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":57},{"date":"2019-11-14T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":43},{"date":"2019-11-15T00:00:00.000Z","utilizationPercentage":43}]
```

Check the demo code here: https://ideone.com/L2rbVe

Answer (score 0):

To avoid iteration over your inputs several times, getting a bad time complexity, I would suggest using Maps and Sets, so you can find related information efficiently.

I kept your function `getDateArray`. As you didn't provide its source, I reproduced it. But you may want to use your own:

```js
const channelsResponse = [{id: 372,name: 'Channel 01',lab: 'Fullerton',tests: [3, 4, 7, 8],},{id: 373,name: 'Channel 02',lab: 'Fullerton',tests: [1, 2, 5, 6],},{id: 374,name: 'Beta Channel',lab: 'Fullerton',tests: [],},{id: 472,name: 'Channel 01',lab: 'Queens',tests: [9, 11, 12, 13],},{id: 473,name: 'Channel 02',lab: 'Queens',tests: [15, 17, 19],},{id: 474,name: 'Channel 03',lab: 'Queens',tests: [21, 22, 24, 25],},{id: 475,name: 'Channel 04',lab: 'Queens',tests: [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],},];

const testsResponse = [{id: 1,start: '2019-11-05T11:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-05T13:05:00Z',},{id: 2,start: '2019-11-06T11:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-06T13:05:00Z',},{id: 3,start: '2019-11-04T11:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-04T13:09:00Z',},{id: 4,start: '2019-11-04T17:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-05T09:32:00Z',},{id: 5,start: '2019-11-11T11:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-12T13:05:00Z',},{id: 6,start: '2019-11-12T14:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-15T13:05:00Z',},{id: 7,start: '2019-11-07T11:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-08T13:05:00Z',},{id: 8,start: '2019-11-08T15:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-08T15:35:00Z',},{id: 9,start: '2019-11-05T09:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-08T12:05:00Z',},{id: 11,start: '2019-11-08T12:35:00Z',end: '2019-11-08T13:35:00Z',},{id: 12,start: '2019-11-08T17:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-11T10:00:00Z',},{id: 13,start: '2019-11-11T12:00:00Z',end: null,},{id: 15},{id: 17,start: '2019-11-05T17:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-06T10:00:00Z',},{id: 19,start: '2019-11-06T12:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-06T13:22:00Z',},{id: 21,start: '2019-11-05T09:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-06T12:05:00Z',},{id: 22,start: '2019-11-08T12:35:00Z',end: '2019-11-08T13:35:00Z',},{id: 24,start: '2019-11-11T17:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-15T10:00:00Z',},{id: 25,start: '2019-11-15T12:00:00Z',},{id: 26,start: '2019-11-05T09:05:00Z',end: '2019-11-06T12:05:00Z',},{id: 27,start: '2019-11-07T12:35:00Z',end: '2019-11-07T13:35:00Z',},{id: 28,start: '2019-11-08T17:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-11T10:00:00Z',},{id: 29,start: '2019-11-12T12:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-12T14:00:00Z',},{id: 30,start: '2019-11-13T12:00:00Z',end: '2019-11-13T14:00:00Z',},];

function getDateArray(start, end) {
    if (!start || !end) return [];
    let date = new Date(start.slice(0,11) + "00:00:00Z");
    let last = Date.parse(end.slice(0,11) + "00:00:00Z");
    let dates = [date.toJSON()];
    while (+date != last) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
        dates.push(date.toJSON());
    }
    return dates; // array of date-strings
}

// Create two maps for faster retrieval
let mapTestToDates = new Map(testsResponse.map(( { id, start, end }) => [id, getDateArray(start, end)]));
let allDates = [...new Set([...mapTestToDates.values()].flat())].sort();
let mapDateToChannels = new Map(allDates.map(date => [date, new Set]));

// Main data collection loop
for (let channel of channelsResponse) {
    for (let test of channel.tests) {
        for (let date of mapTestToDates.get(test)) {
            mapDateToChannels.get(date).add(channel);
        }
    }
}

// Finally calculate the percentages
let result = Array.from(mapDateToChannels.entries(), ([date, channels]) => 
    ({ date, utilizationPercentage: Math.round(channels.size * 100 / channelsResponse.length) })
);

console.log(result);
```